# Unity LineRender texture distorts in Game view

Tags: unity, c#

I have a `LineRenderer` with a tiled texture of repeating arrows. I have a script that scrolls the texture.

However the texture distorts as it moves. The distortion goes back and forth repeating. Without the script the arrows are still distorted in game view so I dont think it is an issue particularly with the scroll.

```
public class LineArrow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float scrollSpeed = 1f;
    public Renderer _renderer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float vOffset = Time.time * scrollSpeed;
        _renderer.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(vOffset, 0));
    }
}
```

The first image is the scene view and the second is the game view

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot or animation of the artifacts you're observing?

Comment: I have added two images now and update my question because it is more of an issue with the texture in game view and not so much with scrolling

Comment: That looks like the expected result when drawing the arrows at such a small size. How would you like these to look instead, with so few pixels to play with?

Comment: But why so different in the game view and fine in the scene view at the same scale. Would there be some compression when running the game do you think?

Comment: It looks like you're zoomed in closer in the scene view, or you're rendering to a lower resolution in game view.

Comment: It looks like you zoomed in to game view  or might be the quality settings which might rendering it to half resolution.